# The site module is not automatically imported during interpreter startup

Tags: python

The question is quite straight forward. As told by the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html), the site package should be automatically imported during initilization. but this is not the case for me. I have to import it mannually to make it work using this:

```
import site
site.main()
```

Also, I'm sure that the directory python\lib which contains site.py is in the search path. And I'm using windows 7.

I'm wondering what is wrong here if any one knows...

Comment: The docs mean that it imports Python's own site module. Not yours.

Comment: I mean Python's own site module. I didn't create one of my own.

Comment: Then why are you trying to call main in it?

Comment: How did you invoke the interpreter?

Comment: This is suggested by the doc:"To explicitly trigger the usual site-specific additions, call the site.main() function."

Comment: By doubel click the shortcut for IDLE on windows desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's undeniably imported at startup, as you can easly verify:

```
import sys
print sys.modules["site"].__file__
```

That doesn't mean any name has been imported into *your* namespace. To do that, you must use `import`. Since the module has already been imported once, you'll get a reference to that module:

```
import site
assert site is sys.modules["site"]
```

In other words, it works like any other module that is imported in some module other than your own.

There's actually not any point in calling `site.main()`, as it's already been called during the import.

Comment: Do you mean I have to use import site and site.main() every time?

Comment: No. `site.main()` has already been called by the time your script does anything. That is, `site.py` contains a line that reads, in its entirety, `main()`. So when the interpreter imports it, `main()` is called.

Comment: It's already working, as i've explained. You don't need to do anything. What exactly do you want to have happen that isn't already happening?

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is cleared now. I wrongly thought it should be in the namespace at first place. I was testing this by put a new folder in the site-packages folder to see if it works without re-import the site which I think is the reason it didn't work at second place. Now it works.